# Android two way data binding on custom View. Cannot find getter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am implementing two way data binding on custom View. I followed the [official android developers](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way#kotlin) but still can't make it work. I have a knob that controlls integer value inside the value property.

```
class ControlKnob(context: Context, attributeSet : android.util.AttributeSet) : RelativeLayout(context, attributeSet), IUIControl {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @BindingAdapter("value")
        fun setValue(knob : ControlKnob, value : Int) {
            if(knob.value != value) {
                knob.value = value
            }

        }

        @JvmStatic
        @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "value")
        fun getValue(knob : ControlKnob) : Int {
            return knob.value
        }

        @JvmStatic
        @BindingAdapter("app:valueAttrChanged")
        fun setListeners( knob : ControlKnob, attrChange : InverseBindingListener) {
            knob.setOnProgressChangedListener {
                attrChange.onChange()
            }
        }
    }
    var value : Int = -1
    set(value) {
        field = value
        valueView.text = stringConverter.invoke(value)
    }
....
....
}
```

Inside layout i use it like this:

```
<cz.abc.def.package.controls.ControlKnob
                    android:id="@+id/knob"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_row="0"
                    android:layout_column="0"
                    app:value="@={viewModel.value}"
                    app:label="Knob" />
```

And my view model:

```
@Bindable
fun getValue() : Int {
    return someValue
}

fun setValue(value : Int) {
    someValue = value

}
```

But still i can't compile it. I get

```
Cannot find a getter for cz.abc.def.package.controls.ControlKnob app:value that accepts parameter type 'int'

If a binding adapter provides the getter, check that the adapter is annotated correctly and that the parameter type matches.
```

What could be the cause of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It turned out that it is not problem with the code. I was missing the `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in the gradle build file. After i added this line into build.gradle in the module it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your listener binding adapter is wrong? Per [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/InverseBindingAdapter), the event listener BindingAdapter value should be `"android:valueAttrChanged"` and you have `"app:valueAttrChanged"`.

Comment: changing the listener binding adapter to android:valueAttrChanged didn't help. Still got the same error